# Assign a custom popup.phtml file through a custom extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Building a custom extension and need to load a new popup.phtml file so we can place our own code into it.

Ive already tried adding it as a package, but I want to avoid this so wondering if theres a way to add this/link to this using an xml layout file for example?

So in short, when a user clicks on the "Track Shipment" link in either the end user account, or the admin clicks the link from Sales > Shipments > View it will load my popup.phtml file and not the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this so here's how I managed to to it just in case it helps anyone else out :)

First of all in the app/etc/modules you'll need to create a file, lets call it Vendor_Module.xml and in there, we'll put the code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then in app/community/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml I added the following;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Vendor_Module_layout module="Vendor_Module">
                    <file>vendor_module.xml</file>
                </Vendor_Module_layout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

In app/design/admin/default/default/layout I created vendor_module.xml and added the following code;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shipping_tracking_popup translate="label">
    <label>Shipment Tracking Popup</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/popuper.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="shipping/tracking_popup" name="shipping.tracking.popup" template="shipping/tracking/popuper.phtml" />
    </reference>
</shipping_tracking_popup>
```

In app/design/frontend/base/default/layout I created another vendor_module.xml file and added the code;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
    <shipping_tracking_popup>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="shipping/tracking_popup" name="shipping.tracking.popup" template="Vendor/shipping/tracking/popup.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </shipping_tracking_popup>
</layout>
```

Finally, in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/Vendor/shipping/tracking I created a new file called popup.phtml and then added my own required code that I wanted displayed here.  The following code is just example code that will add some text and a close button.

```
<div class="page-title title-buttons">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Tracking Information'); ?></h1>
    <button class="button" onclick="window.close(); window.opener.focus();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?></span></span></button>
</div>

<!-- Add Your Stuff Here -->

<div class="buttons-set">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Close Window')) ?>" class="button" onclick="window.close(); window.opener.focus();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

Thats it, hope it helps!